# mergeDebugResources (String-array in strings.xml)

Tags: android, arrays, string, android-resources

I am watching a android studio tutorial but have an error message.

i found out strings.xml have string-array tag with name of "items". However, they cannot be brought to MainActivity.java.

Error is "mergeDebugResources"

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">List App</string>
    <String-array name="items">
        <item>peach</item>
        <item>tomato</item>
        <item>squash</item>
    </String-array>
</resources>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView myListView;
    String[] items;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Resources res=getResources();
        myListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        items=res.getStringArray(R.array.items);
    }
}
```

Please explain to me why the error happened! Thank you so much!

Comment: `<String-array>` or `<string-array>`?  It should be in lower case.

Comment: @bcm14, find the attached url http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-creating-and-populating-listview-items-in-xml/. thank u

Comment: Please edit your post and attach the full error message